# Redundancy Query

Tags: resignation, layoff

I work as a night carer one night per week looking after 2 residents.

One resident ended up very ill in hospital for a few weeks and the other was too high dependency for the care setting -she also had been unwell.

I have been working there 19 years and there has been a new manager in the last six months.

Due to the situation with their health and a health complaint I recently had I asked could I be made redundant, was it likely they would be moved in the near future  and was told no - as my job was still there and they would replace me and they might move the one who was in hospital but the other resident would not be moving. They said I could leave as soon as possible if I wanted and they followed up twice the following week to get my written resignation.

I have since found out the following week after I left they moved the resident who had went to hospital to a nursing home and the other resident to a place that looks after higher dependency residents.

They then offered all remaining night carers redundancy and never replaced me. I don't believe redundancies can just be put together in a week -week and a half and redundancy was something that was an option being put in place and the information I based handing in my notice on was false.

What do you advise I feel they are pulling a fast one on me thinking I have no interaction with the other employees being in only one night on my own and that I will never find out that the others got redundancy payments and not me but I do have contact with other employees and they are not aware of this it seems

Comment: I am confused, you asked if they could fire you, they said they wanted to keep you, so in response you've resigned, I assume for some greener pasture. What's the issue/question we can help you with there?

Comment: Hi I thought the care facility would be closing so I asked could they make me redundant and they told me no they had no plans to close.I left because of a health issue . My issue is they look like they did have plans  to close and offer redundancies because they moved the two residents within a week and a half after me leaving and had offered redundancy to the other carers a week after they got my written resignation. I would not have handed in notice if I thought there was redundancies on offer as I would be due a sum

Comment: Your choosing to leave before you had to is in no way their fault. Yes, you might have gotten a severance payment if you had stayed, but you didn't. Sorry, but you made your choice and that's the end of it.

Answer (score 4):

You took a Gamble and if everything you suspect is true, you lost.

Is it scummy? Perhaps.

But here's the thing - You quitting of your own free will is almost always much cheaper than redundancy. Therefore the company is incentivized not to make you redundant.

If what you suspected was true, you should have waited. Depending on your location, there may be rules around consultation requirements - essentially you should wait until a formal announcement.

Then, once such an announcement is made, you ask to see what the voluntary redundancy package looks like.

Comment: Yes OK- As I said if they had plans for redundancies they didn't tell the truth and that is my issue  asI did ask about it- also I should have worked out a longer notice period given I was there 19 years  but they wanted me to leave within a week, had I worked out the proper notice then I would have been there when redundancies were announced. Its just a shame I trusted what I was told

Comment: @user141014 None tells the truth, until they are ready to announce redundancies (or whatever).  Why would you be privy to their internal discussions?

Answer (score 2):

They may have been honest at the time you asked. Situations change.

Or they may have been instructed on how to answer this by upper management and just been doing the jobs they were hired to do, which is unpleasant but also sometimes happens.

Don't shoot the messengers, and remember that a verbal promise is worth only the paper it is printed on.

The proper response to worrying about being let go is to start preparing your resume and otherwise getting ready to start a job search the moment this turns real. If you're really worried, start the search earlier. In no case quit unless you absolutely must; keep doing your job well, take the paychecks while you can get them, and you might be on the lucky side of the scissors.

Comment: Thanks this person is upper management ,there has to be a degree of planning before moving people  so I doubt they were honest. I'll  get some legal advice and confront them with the facts - I  understand the replies here  but I am dealing with a religious  organisation and they may not want this type of  morally questionable behaviour towards long serving staff to be made public -doesn't exactly match their ethos.I also point that I was looking after a high dependency person without any training and this was too much for me health wise so I had to leave

Comment: Thank you Keshlam I have a job, this was a part time job I did alongside my main job  and I won't take another part time job.

Comment: You're entitled to doubt. You're unlikely to win an argument, in court, or in public opinion. You chose to leave rather than wait. You get to live with consequences of that decision.